# I made a C++ constructor with a string, but it won't print the string out

Tags: c++, string, constructor

What I did was the following I made a class called `TheSecondVeryBestClassEverMade` (I already made the best class ever made previously, so that's why!) made a constructor and in the parameter I made a string z. In the body of this constructor I revered to another function (it's a function in C++ right, and method in Java?) and set the string name to z.

After that I made a object from the `TheSecondVeryBestClassEverMade`, and in its parameters I made a string that said: "Mambo Number 5 is my jam!" (because it's a great song right?!) but now the darn thing won't print out in the terminal.

What am I doing wrong here?

Here is my c++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

//Constructor is a function that gets called automatically when a object is made.
// No more explicitly calling of the function, does it automatically!

class TheSecondVeryBestClassEverMade{
    public:
    //Constructors never have a return type so nothing gets returned in the body. 
    // Constructor name == as the class name:
    TheSecondVeryBestClassEverMade(string z){
        //DONT print anything out in a constructor, only IDIOTS do that.
        // Are you a idiot? No don't think so buddy!
        //Normally its used to give variables a initial value. EXAMPLE TIME:
        setTheSecondVeryBestName(z);
    }
    void setTheSecondVeryBestName(string bb){
        name = bb;
    }
    string getTheSecondVeryBestName(){
        return name;
    }

private:
    string name;
};

int main() {
    TheSecondVeryBestClassEverMade bodyOder("Mambo Number 5 is my jam baby!");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't have any output in your code (as `std::cout << bodyOder.getTheSecondVeryBestName()`). so no display is the console is expected.

Comment: "but now the darn thing won't print out in the terminal" Well, you don't call any function that would make any ouput to stdout. Use the initializer list to initialize class members from parameters passed to the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

You made `bodyOder` and gave it a string in its constructor which you then correctly set... but you don't have any code that actually prints it. Add something like

```
void printName(){
    std::cout << "Name: " << name << std::endl;
}
```

And call that after making `bodyOder`:

```
int main()
{
    TheSecondVeryBestClassEverMade bodyOder("Mambo Number 5 is my jam baby!");
    bodyOder.printName();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks I totally saw that my question came out wrong, forget to edit the title and stuff. Thanks that you gave a look anyways, and helped me out! 

I see what i did wrong now, quite simple actually. I maybe should've thought about it before posting.

Anyways much appreciated.

Keep coding brother!

EDIT: forgetting to edit the title and some of the body is a lesson for next time, I know what to do now and I learned from my experience. That's probably the most important thing right?

Comment: Shouldn't it be public string instead of void? Void doesn't return anything (its like a empty space) ...

Comment: No problem! Everyone makes mistakes. Yes, you can do `public string`, and return your `string`. What you then have is a getter, and then you can instead do the print in a different function, for instance in `main`, like this: `cout << "Name: " << bodyOder.getName() << std::endl;`

Comment: Haven't heard of that term yet, cool learned something new :D Thanks man,

Comment: `public void` is a syntax error in C++. You're thinking of Java. Drop the `public`

Comment: I gadda say I love the part of c++ where you don't have to put public in front of every new function (or method in java) you make. And there are some points I love about Java as well (been working in c++ for a while nothing shoots into my mind right now but I guess you can think of something). They both have there advantages and disadvantages I guess... Not to try to sound arrogant or anything ( I hate people who are arrogant) but why do people think c++ is harder to learn than Java? I think of them as both other sides of the same coin....

Comment: Alright, fixed that `public` issue. From my experience, it's mostly pointers and memory management that people are having difficulties with that is easier to handle in Java. In Java, it's much simpler, but in C (and C++) it gives you more control over what's happening under the hood.

Comment: Adding a `printName` member is not good design. Keep a separation of concerns.

Comment: So in theory its always better to learn c++ first right (to get more control over your coding and the pointers and memory management really learns you how things are handled and what you are doing),and than go to the (I dare to say ) easier stuff like Java and for example Python? Altough I'm going to learn those three simultaneously since you don't want to forget one language while learning the other...

Comment: @Thomas I thought it was a nice touch to make use of them both ;) Needed to learn that you can make another object to let c++ output another string... I know where you are coming from though, and I get your point... No worries brother!